# How to set DENY permissions on a data user

Tags: sql-server, database-security

For a .net application we can store database connectionstrings like so

```
<connectionstrings config="cnn.config" />
```

I am trying to get as little as permissions as possible but there always seems to be a different way. To get info.

I am using the settings because they are more secure for one and two I have other people working on my application.

So I've set

```
USE database_name;
GRANT EXECUTE TO [security_account];
```

So the user can execute commands that's fine.

Then I've got `db_reader` and `db_writer` so they can read and write and this seems like a perfect marriage.

Still bad news the user can login and see the tables and store procedures definitions but not alter them, however, they can still see them.

How can I set the permissions to where the user can read, write. execute, and that is it PERIOD!?

Comment: Tag the dbms used, the answer will probably be product specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being able to see the definition of tables, stored procedures, etc is governed by the `VIEW DEFINITION` permission. So you can do:

```
DENY VIEW DEFINITION TO [yourUser];
```

And that user won't be able to see the definition for any object in the database. This also includes the ability to see other users.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop the user from viewing the sp definition you need to specify the `WITH ENCRYPTION` option in the sp.

Adding a user to the `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` role and granting EXECUTE will limit the user to reading writing and executing but they will still be able to see the sp definition by using the `sp_helptext` stored procedure and `sys.sql_modules` catalog view. See [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2964/encrypting-and-decrypting-sql-server-stored-procedures-views-and-userdefined-functions/) for more information on sp and funciton encryption.

```
exec sp_addrolemember @rolename =  'db_datareader', @membername = 'testUser'
exec sp_addrolemember @rolename =  'db_datawriter', @membername = 'testUser'
GRANT EXECUTE TO testUser;
```

You can create an sp the `WITH ENCRYPTION` option by adding it before the `AS` keyword like this. See the WITH ENCRYPTION section of the CREATE PROCEDURE definition [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE HumanResources.uspEncryptThis
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
   SELECT BusinessEntityID, JobTitle, NationalIDNumber, VacationHours, SickLeaveHours 
   FROM HumanResources.Employee;
GO
```

You can also alter functions by adding it after the returns keyword.

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.getHash ( @inputString VARCHAR(20) )
RETURNS VARBINARY(8000) WITH ENCRYPTION
```